# dijit.form.DateTextBox is not visible when the page is loaded

Tags: spring-webflow, spring-js

When my page is loaded I cannot see calendar:
[image]

When I click on the birthday field of the form it appears, but it does not look as I expect:
[image]

The code I use to display in jsp file:

```
    <label for="birthday">Birthday<br/> </label>
          <sf:input path="birthday" id="birthday"
                 pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[012])-[0-9]{4}"/><br/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
              elementId:"birthday",
              widgetType:"dijit.form.DateTextBox",
              widgetAttrs:{ datePattern:"dd-MM-yyyy", required:true }}));
    </script>
```

So my questions are:

1. How to make calendar always visible as soon as the form is loaded?
2. How can I manage with its css, so I could set backgournd and other properties via css file? If it is not possible, then via JavaScript params.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order the calendar works I had to set the following css class to the html body element:

```
<body class="tundra">
```

It helped.